# How to use KeepassXC SSH Agent in linux terminal?

Tags: ssh

I have KeePass configured on Windows machine and SSH connnections with KeeAgent works great in Windows Terminal and Putty. Now i have new machine with linux and I'm trying to configure KeepassXC to use SSH connnections with SSH Agent in terminal. I think I did everything in KeepassXC (add new entry, turn on SSH Agent, add SSH key etc.) correctly. When I type `ssh-add -l` in terminal I can see that SSH key is loaded. But when I'm trying to login to the server I'm still asked for password... Please help.

Greetings,
Martin

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! [How do I use KeePassXC as an SSH agent?](https://superuser.com/questions/1595123/) on SuperUser.SE should have what you need.